# Architectural Addon - Export UV for handcraft paper models

Tags: uv, add-on

I can remember watching a video about architectural-design-addons in blender. At some point the youtuber said that it was possible to export the uv for handcrafting. Like these paper kits for children. Well now is the time I could benefit from this. Sadly I wasn't logged into youtube and can't find the video anymore. Does anybody know what addon could do this? example: [image]

EDIT: I found a similiar addon but I dont think it can work for me. https://github.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender#export-paper-model-from-blender

Comment: Hello :). It could be [Export Paper Model](https://blender-addons.org/export-paper-model-addon/) addon, that is shipped with Blender. Just enable it in Preferences > Addons.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the one and only. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jachym Michal solved this issue. Its the "Export Paper Model" addon, preinstalled in blender. Thank you again!